# Oracle DBA Newbie - Maintenance Outline

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I need your help. We have an old Oracle 10g database and I would like your recommendations on what maintenance tasks should be performed and when. e.g. #1 update fixed stats once a month, #2 Update table statistics once a week, #3 check for index fragmentation weekly and rebuild table column indexes when "x".

does anyone have any maintenance checklists or outlines some sort of guide of what needs to be checked?

Any help is appreciated.

nothing yet has been done

Comment: This is really a question for dba.stackexchange.com, as it isn't really about software development.

Comment: Upgrade to a supported version

Comment: If you have a database that old (and we have many even older, so I understand that upgrading in the real world is often not feasible), I would leave it alone. Don't do anything that's not already being done. Just monitor it.